# Visual Studio 2017 dotnet crash when changing target build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, x86, target

At the moment I am building application in C#, in Visual Studio 2017.
I need to change target build from "AnyPC" to "x86"(to be able to call some unmanaged dlls which are written in C).
But when I am just changing target build in Configuration Manager(or in Properties)->switch to x86 platform/target; And after this I run the application,dotnet is crashing and error appears:"dotnet has stopped working".

I think I need somehow to use dotnet-x86 when compiling for x86 target, and to use dotnet(x64) when compiling for x64,somehow to add their paths but I have no idea how to do that. I hope you can help me guys

P.S:I am working on Windows 10 x64, VS-2017 Community, using .NET core 2.0

my program:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Need Help");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output from Debug:'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.6\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[7276] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 255 (0xff).

Or with disabled "Just My Code":'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.6\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[1764] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 255 (0xff).

[image of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyCFF.png)

Comment: Are you sure you're not actually using these C DLLs or any alternate libraries when you change your build target?  Is it possible to write code in C# that breaks on 32-bit platforms but works on 64-bit?  If so, maybe you've done that, and AnyPC is using 64-bit instead of gimping itself with 32-bit code?

Comment: yes, I made a project apart which is not related with these dlls anyway the app is crashing(dotnet stopped working)

Comment: When you use the debugger, which machine instruction is leading to the crash?  (or at least what function is it in?)  Or if it's not a CPU exception from storing to a bad address or dividing by zero or whatever, then what *is* causing your dotnet runtime to stop?  Can you make a [mcve] including exact build instructions to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I added some additional information about my problem in description, hope this can be somehow helpful

Comment: "has stopped working" is a nearly useless error message.  Turn off "Just My Code" to find out what really happened.  Even if *you* don't understand / can't debug assembly language, adding that info to your question might help someone who can (and knows about .NET, which I don't >.<) tell you why this is happening, or how your install might be broken or whatever the problem is.  Failing on a totally trivial program seems like a problem.

Comment: With "Just My Code" disabled: 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.6\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[9392] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thankfully I found the right answer for my problem:  https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7532

---

The .NET Core CLI team mentioned the fix is as follows:

> Install both the x86 and x64 .NET Core 2.0 SDKs from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core. Put the following in a file named Directory.Build.targets that is somewhere above your project file (e.g. the root of the source repository). MSBuild will pick it up automatically for all projects:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup 
      Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' and
                 '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' and
                 '$(SelfContained)' != 'true'"
                  >
    <RunCommand Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x86'">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\dotnet\dotnet</RunCommand>
    <RunCommand Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x64'">$(ProgramW6432)\dotnet\dotnet</RunCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```